# automated testing frameworks?

Tags: php, testing, automation

how can i automate testing of a web based application?

What are some frameworks that i can use to write scripts that will run automatically / on demand and indicate success or failure?

Comment: What are you using ASP.NET, PHP, etc?

Comment: sorry - php, but should it make a difference to a ui based framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

We have set up a hook with SVN so that on a commit, PHPUnit is run.

I would imagine you could do the same with git/CVS or whatever version control you use.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft has a awesome [framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) for generating, coding, and running automated UI tests, which is included with Visual Studio 2010.

You can use TFS to run your tests on demand or in response to a continuous integration.

Comment: thanks - any change it'll work with php applications? in any case, i dont think it;ll be free, would it?? :)

Comment: It will work with any web application, it hooks in through the control id's I believe. However, yes, you have to have visual studio 2010, and if your organization doesn't own licenses already, there might be more cost effective solutions out there.